# facebook API extended permissions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with extended permissions to my app.
When i have no facebook connection session (!Facebook::getSession()) iam reloading page to Facebook::getLoginUrl(array())

This URL returned is concretly https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=153862711317576&cancel_url=http://www.praguebistro.cz/facebook/chance/web/&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http://www.praguebistro.cz/facebook/chance/web/&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=read_stream,email,user_photos

**When iam logged into Facebook URL is automaticaly reloaded into Permissions confirm URL, but without perms parameters.
Anyone to know how can i fix this?**

Thank you V.M.

Comment: Jesus! When i click it, everything's ok, but after autoreload from app problem persist wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - FB does not understand when you'll encode URL into entities. I forced to reload it unencoded and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will ignore all permission requests silently if the application already has them. Remove the requested permissions from your privacy settings and it will work as intended.

Comment: Iam not confirming it, so i cannot have them. Iam only trying to get the same confirm window (email data) at http://apps.facebook.com/praguebistrochance/ like it is upper in my post. Its the same link

Comment: Try testing with a blan new account. :)